# Draw x number of sprites on repeat

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game using python and pygame. For the game I allow the user to input how many people are playing. The programme is then meant to draw this number of sprites. Here is my code :

```
for i in range (0,playercount):
    numbase = str(i)
    playerbase = 'player'
    playername = playerbase + numbase
    print(playername)
    playername = player(RED, 16, 16, 0)
    playername.rect.x = (700)
    playername.rect.y = (700)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

'player' is a class that will draw the sprite , I have tested it and it works when I type in the desired play name manually.

What I am trying to do in the loop is draw (for example) 3 different objects named player0,player1 and player2. I can see why it's not working , it is taking 'playername' literally instead of as a variable. But I'm not sure how to fix this.

There may be a better way of approaching this entirely , if so I am open to other solutions.

Comment: Does your `player` class inherit from [pygame.sprite.Sprite()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)? If not, you should change it to do so and take advantage of the built-in functionality, e.g. use a [Group()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) to manage multiple sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code below. I've changed the layout of your code to have a list of players instead of trying to do whatever you were trying to do with your basename thing. This creates a list of three players in two different ways (take your pick depending on what you're trying to do).

Then, I loop through the list using a `for i in iterator` syntax which allows you to loop through a list without having to keep track of the index.

I recommend reading a python tutorial about [lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). If you ever find yourself writing code where variables are named `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, etc, then you should probably be using a list or other aggregate data type.

```py
#Makes 3 identical players
players = [player(RED, 16, 16, 0) for _ in range(playercount)]
#OR
#Makes 3 different players and adds them to a list
players = []
players.append(player(RED, 16, 16, 0))
players.append(player(BLUE, 16, 16, 0))
players.append(player(GREEN, 16, 16, 0))

for p in players:
    #I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here, this is 
    #more implementation specific and because I don't know
    #what you're trying to do, I just converted the code you had above 
    #to use the updated looping method. 
    p.rect.x = (700)
    p.rect.y = (700)
    pygame.display.flip()
```